# Different ways in implementing readable streams of Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have come across two different ways of implementing `readable` streams.But I am not sure what is the difference between them and why at-least one of them doesn't throw error.

Method 1:

```
const stream = require('stream');
const readable = stream.Readable;
```

Method 2:

```
const stream = require('stream').Stream;
const readable = stream.Readable;
```

Comment: In both methods readable is `undefined`.

Comment: Did you mean `require('stream').Stream.Readable`?

Comment: @SuhailGupta. Yes. It is Stream.Readable.